# Connect Ormlite to Existing SQlite database on Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ormlite

i have started to learn how to manage data with ormlite, but i have some problem when i try to connect and existing db with this orm.

I have a class that represent the table in my db, and i annotate with DatabaseTable and Databasefield.

But, when i try to do a query, i get an error like "Table xxxx does not exists" (the name of the table is correct).

There is an example somewhere that teach me how to connect db and ormlite in android? 
I have searched everywhere....=(